# IntelliJ - Git hooks : terraform: command not found

Tags: git, intellij-idea, terraform, githooks

Environment :

- Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
- oh-my-zsh
- IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5 (Community Edition)

---

The problem :

I have a git hook `pre-commit` set globally like this :

```bash
git config --global core.hooksPath <PATH_TO_HOOK_FILE>
```

In this git hook I call terraform commands like this :

```bash
terraform fmt
terraform init
terraform plan
```

I have installed [terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/install?product_intent=terraform) with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

In my terminal inside **ANY** git project on my machine, when I try to commit, everything works like a charm :

```bash
git commit -m "My commit message"
```

```
inventories.tf
module.tf
Success! The configuration is valid.

[main 559149a] My commit message
 3 file changed, 6 insertion(+), 5 deletion(-)
```

But when I am using `IntelliJ Idea` -> `Commit view` to commit I am having this error :

```
/home/.../pre-commit: line 57: terraform: command not found
```

When I change it to the full path of the command (i.e. /toto/titi/terraform) inside the hooks file it works.

So my question is : How can I tell IntelliJ where is Terraform executable ?

I've already tried setting the full path in `Settings` -> `Tools` -> `Terraform` (not working) and even selecting "Terraform fmt" in Commits option does not work.

---

EDIT :

As pointed out by [Dino Letic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21804501/dino-letic), the issue was that IntelliJ need to load terminal environment variable (which I thought was done automatically).

To fix this, either start it in a terminal or simply install it using [IntelliJ toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) if you prefer starting it as an application.

---

EDIT 2 :

IntelliJ, when started as an application and not from the terminal, uses the ~/.profile to load variables like PATH.

Simply edit the file to add your binary path to the PATH variable and your all set :

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:<PATH_TO_YOUR_BINS>
```

Comment: you haven't put any debugging effort into this -- "command not found" 99.99% of the time is "I need to figure out what $PATH is".  it's also unlikely to help other people

Comment: Thanks for the input ! But to be fair I did put some effort and tried to figure out what the problem was but it seems we can no longer be linux nweebies on SO :) Anyway, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ide should inherit env variables from default terminal. If these paths are detected in terminal, can you start IDE inside terminal, does it work?

Comment: That was it, it seems like you need to either intall it from the toolbox provided by intellij or start it from a terminal for environment variables to work. Thanks for the input <3